# Pushing a Duplicate View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sigabrt

I'm trying to build a step by step questionnaire app with a View Controller called QuestionController whose content is dynamically populated via some globals in a constants file. When a user is done answering a question, I want to be able to be able to push another QuestionController for the next question.

```
@IBAction func goNext(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let controller = QuestionController()

    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

}
```

As you can see, that is exactly as I have done but for whatever reason I'm getting a SIBABRT error. Any ideas why this might be? I don't have any lingering outlets and the only action is the next button callback you see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
let controller = QuestionController()
```

load it like this with it's identifer in IB

```
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "identifer") as! QuestionController
```

Comment: Okay, let me give it a go and get back to you. But what difference does this make? What is the reasoning for it?

Comment: a VC is either loaded from xib , IB or created programmatically , in your case you use **let controller = QuestionController()** which loads it successfully if you only created it programmatically , but since it's in IB all associated outlets and IB design will go to nil